# C#: yield return within a foreach fails - body cannot be an iterator block

Tags: c#, iterator, yield

Consider this bit of obfuscated code. The intention is to create a new object on the fly via the anonymous constructor and `yield return` it. The goal is to avoid having to maintain a local collection just to simply `return` it.

```
public static List<DesktopComputer> BuildComputerAssets()
{           
    List<string> idTags = GetComputerIdTags();

    foreach (var pcTag in idTags)
    {
        yield return new DesktopComputer() {AssetTag= pcTag
                                          , Description = "PC " + pcTag
                                          , AcquireDate = DateTime.Now
                                           };
    }            
}
```

Unfortunately, this bit of code produces an exception:

> Error 28  The body of 'Foo.BuildComputerAssets()' cannot be an iterator block because 'System.Collections.Generic.List' is not an iterator interface type

**Questions**

- What does this error message mean?
- How can I avoid this error and use `yield return` properly?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can only use `yield return` in a function that returns an `IEnumerable` or an `IEnumerator`, not a `List<T>`.

You need to change your function to return an `IEnumerable<DesktopComputer>`.

Alternatively, you can rewrite the function to use [`List<T>.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx):

```
return GetComputerIdTags().ConvertAll(pcTag => 
    new DesktopComputer() {
        AssetTag    = pcTag,
        Description = "PC " + pcTag,
        AcquireDate = DateTime.Now
    });
```

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: @LampPost: Because `yield return` creates an IEnumerator implementation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators#enumeration-sources-with-iterator-methods

Answer (score 18):

Your method signature is wrong.  It should be:

```
public static IEnumerable<DesktopComputer> BuildComputerAssets()
```

Answer (score 10):

[yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0(VS.80).aspx) only works on Iterator types:

> The yield statement can only appear inside an iterator block

[Iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0(VS.80).aspx) are defined as

> The return type of an iterator must be IEnumerable, IEnumerator, IEnumerable<T>, or IEnumerator<T>.

IList and IList<T> do implement IEnumerable/IEnumerable<T>, but every caller to an enumerator expects one of the four types above and none else.

Answer (score 1):

You could also implement the same functionality using a LINQ query (in C# 3.0+). This is less efficient than using `ConvertAll` method, but it is more general. Later, you may also need to use other LINQ features such as filtering:

```
return (from pcTag in GetComputerIdTags()
        select new DesktopComputer() { 
          AssetTag    = pcTag, 
          Description = "PC " + pcTag, 
          AcquireDate = DateTime.Now 
        }).ToList();
```

The `ToList` method converts the result from `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>`. I personally don't like `ConvertAll`, because it does the same thing as LINQ. But because it was added earlier, it cannot be used with LINQ (it should have been called `Select`).